# WP7 AutoCompleteBox Popup position

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, autocompletebox

The toolkit:AutoCompleteBox in WP7 "opens" the Popup with results above the textfield. I need this Popup to be below the TextBox. 
Wasted hours on this. finally, i've written my own autoCompleteBox with a ListBox opening below.

Just out of curiosity, pleas tell me how it shold be with the "original" one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue and this is how I solved it, using [Perspective Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470131%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and `RenderTransform` in the borders of Popup in the default template.

```
<Popup>
  <Grid>
   <Border>
   <Border.Projection> 
    <PlaneProjection GlobalOffsetX="-10" GlobalOffsetY="37" CenterOfRotationY="1" CenterOfRotationX="0" RotationX="180"/>
   </Border.Projection>
   <Border>
    <Border.Projection>
     <PlaneProjection RotationX="-180"/>
    </Border.Projection>
    <ListBox/>
   </Border>
  </Border>
 </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Change `GolbalOffsetX` and `GlobalOffsetY` according to your textbox height and width.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default property that will define the location for the popup in the `AutoCompleteBox` control.