# Autocompletebox + TransitionService = no joy

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm struggling with a xaml page in my app. I have a scrollviewer containing a few buttons, and then a grid below containing an Autocompletebox. It's working like it should. But when I apply the TransitionService from the latest Silverlight toolkit, the autocompletebox's suggestions-popup gets "centered", so half of the suggestions is "under" the keyboard. It's working perfectly on all the other pages. The transition itself is working, it's just the placement of the popup from the autocompletebox that get's funky.
I've tried to remove the Scrollviewer, and used a Grid instead, but the same happends.

This is the code for the transitions:

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Simplified code, it's more buttons in the code.
And:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="buttons">
            <Button Content="Vis alle navn i en liste" Name="cmdShowInList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="cmdShowInList_Click"></Button>                
            </StackPanel>            
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="Search" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="txtSearch" FontSize="32" Text="Search here" Width="330" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FilterMode="Custom" MouseEnter="txtSearch_MouseEnter" DropDownClosed="txtSearch_DropDownClosed">
            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
        <Button Name="cmdGoToName" Content="Show" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="cmdGoToName_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

Is this a know issue, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't know how the NavigationService works, but try to set the ContentHorizontalAlignement for your popup to be Left, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I found out that there is no solution to this, in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251785/wp7-autocompletebox-popup-position