# Toolkit Autocompletebox popup postition

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocompletebox

I'm having some troubles with the position of the Autocompletebox. It's working as it should, displaying the popup above the textbox when using the app. But if I use a task like `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.EmailComposeTask` and then click on the back button, the position of the popup goes to to the "middle", not below or over the textbox, but right over it. Does anybody have a clue on what I need to do here? I know that the app is deactivated and activated again when i use `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.EmailComposeTask`. But I don't understand why the popup of the toolkit:Autocompletebox is the only thing that's affected by this.

I've read this thread: [WP7 AutoCompleteBox Popup position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251785/wp7-autocompletebox-popup-position), but is there still no way of "fixing" this issue? Any tips?